# ...,for they will surely tear us to pieces... Meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

In Longman online English dictionary I saw a sentence:

> We are lost, for they will surely tear us to pieces with their sharp claws.

What is the meaning of **for they will surely** here?

Is it somehow linked to **for sure?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just as a side note: *We are lost* here doesn't mean they don't know where they are, or are misplaced, it means they are dead (or will be once they've been torn to pieces).

Answer (score 1):

*"For they will surely..."* means that they will definitely do whatever action is mentioned in the phrase. In this case, they will definitely "*tear us to pieces..."*

You are correct in suggesting that this is related to *"For Sure"* in terms of meaning.

---

Side Note, but the reason this phrase may be confusing to new English Speakers is because of the strange placement of *"for."*  I can't think of the exact way to describe it, but it is common to hear phrases like these in overly dramatic scripts or older literature.

Another Example: "Anita could not return to England, for she had lost her passport"

Comment: Could you give me another example

Comment: "Anita could not return to England, for she had lost her passport"

 It isn't the sort of English you may hear every day, but it is grammatically correct English nonetheless.